# How to create an inventory using a class

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, dictionary

I am doing a project creating an inventory for a home builder. I am stuck on two things. 
1) While everything is running the the class as I need it, it is not saving and information to my dictionary. Everything is running correctly, but after inputting the information to add a home it does not add the home to Allhomes. Because of this I can't check to see if the other functions are working however the else part if saying the home could not be found.
2) Updating the sale status. After writing everything I'm not sure how to now update the sale status with it being part of home_info. Any suggestions would be great.

Thank you.

```
Allhomes = {}

class Home_Inventory:

    def __init__(self, squarefeet, address, city, state, zipcode, modelname, salestatus):
        self.squarefeet = squarefeet + "square feet"
        self.address = address
        self.city = city
        self.state = state
        self.zipcode = zipcode
        self.modelname = modelname
        self.salestatus = salestatus

    def add_home(self):
        address = input("Enter address: ")
        city = input("Enter city: ")
        state = input("Enter state: ")
        zipcode = input("Enter zip code: ")
        squarefeet = input("Enter square footage: ")
        modelname = input("What is the model?: ")
        salestatus = input("Is the home sold, available, or under contract?: ")

        home_info = Home_Inventory(address, city, state, zipcode, squarefeet + " square feet", modelname, salestatus)
        full_address = (address, city, state, zipcode)
        home_stats = (squarefeet + " square feet", modelname, salestatus)
        Allhomes = {full_address: home_stats}

        print("Home added successfully")

    def delete_home(self):
        delete = input("What is the full address of the home you want to delete?: ")
        if delete in Allhomes.keys():
            del[delete]
            print("The home entered has been deleted.")
        else:
            print("Address not found")


    def sale_status(self):
        update = input("What is the full address of the home you want to update?:")
        if update in Allhomes.keys():
            pass
        else:
            print("Address not found")


user=True
while user:
    print("1. Add to home inventory")
    print("2. Remove home from inventory")
    print("3. Update sale status")
    print("4. View inventory")
    print("5. Exit program")
    user_wants=input("What would you like to do today?")
    if user_wants=="1":
        Home_Inventory.add_home(input)
    elif user_wants=="2":
        Home_Inventory.delete_home(input)
    elif user_wants=="3":
        Home_Inventory.sale_status(input)
    elif user_wants=="4":
        print(Allhomes)
    elif user_wants=="5":
        print("\n Thank you for using home invertory.")
        break
    elif user_wants!="":
        print("\n Input not understood. Please try again.")`
```

Comment: You should probably create `Home` objects, that contain a `SaleStatus` object, and an `Address` object - these `Home` objects can then be stored in a `HomeInventory` object that gives you methods to manage the inventory. As it is, it is hard to understand why a `HomeInventory` object should worry about the details of the address of a single `Home`.